# .Net: Calling SignalR Hub from Outside Controller or Hub

Tags: c#, .net, azure, signalr, azureservicebus

I have been able to add a SignalR Hub to my .Net application with the following code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace SignalR.Hubs
{
    public class SampleHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task AddUserToGroup(int groupId, string name)
        {
            string groupName = groupId.ToString();
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
            string message = $"{name} has been added to the group.";
            await Clients.GroupExcept(groupName, Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("ConnectionOpenedMessage", message);
        }
    }
};
```

and I can call this hub from a controller:

```
        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ApiCallController(int Id, [FromBody] List<string> list)
        {
            var response = await DoSomeCommand(Id, 0, list);

            await sampleHub.Clients.Group(assessmentId.ToString()).SendAsync("ApiRouteCalled", $"A user has called the api route.", list);
            
            return response;
        }
```

I have also added the necessary code in the web api startup.  This code all works and I am able to open a connection to the hub, call the api and have it return the message through the hub.

However, I would like to be able to do this exact scenario from outside of the controller.  For example, I would like be able to access this sample hub from a service bus web job with code like this:

```
using SignalR.Hubs;

namespace ServiceBusReceiversWebJob.Receivers
{
    public class ActionReceiver : IMessageReceiver<ActionMessage>
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<SampleHub> sampleHub;
        public ActionReceiver(
            IHubContext<SampleHub> sampleHub
            )
        {
            this.sampleHub = sampleHub;
        }

        public async Task HandleMessageAsync(ActionMessage message)
        {
            await sampleHub.Clients.Group(message.AssessmentId.ToString()).SendAsync("TEST", $"The service bus has received a request.");
        }
    }
}
```

This WebJob code does not return any errors based on how it is written, however it does not seem to actually send a message to the group as intended like it does in the api controller.  I attempted to set the add the SignalR to the services to the WebJobs startup but this has also made no difference.

I have moved the Hub itself to both the Core layer and the Services layer with the same outcome either way.  More relevant code:
WebApi Startup:

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<SampleHub>("/hubs/hubconnected");
            });

                services.AddSignalR();

                services.AddScoped<Hub, SampleHub>();
```

and in the WebJob:

```
                services.AddSignalR();

                services.AddScoped<Hub, SampleHub>();
```

How would I go about being able to access a hub from outside of the web api controller within the project?

Comment: If you have to call business logic from more than one place (e.g. a SignalR hub and a controller), you should move it into a service layer (e.g. UserService). Register the service with DI and inject it into both your hub and your controller

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try and see if that works the way I am trying to get it to work.

Comment: I should have mentioned that before, I had the Hub itself in the Core layer.  The WebApi startup had the app.UseEndpoints... added to it as well as the services.AddSignalR();   I have since moved the Hub from the Core layer into the Services layer and added services.AddSignalR(); and services.AddScoped<Hub, SampleHub>(); to the WebJob startup, but none of this has worked as I am expecting, even moving it to different layers, the WebApi Controller still has access to it but the WebJob still doesn't.  I am sure I am injecting it wrong but I just don't know how.  Will add this relevant code above

Comment: I think you are putting too much weight into my comment on the layer. In reality it matters less about the actual layer it's in. What's most important is that you create a new class (UserService) that handles the common logic. Registering that new class with DI allows it to be injected into your hub, controllers, or another service.

Comment: Regarding the layers: Services can be kept in your core layer, or put into their own layer. Typically controllers and SignalR hubs would be in your API layer if you have one. There's no universally ideal architecture, these are just some common practices

Comment: I think I am somewhat following (maybe not) but not sure if that would work with the architecture I am confined with.  Essentially, I have this scenario: client makes api call => api calls webjob => webjob performs async task => once task is complete, send message to clients connected in a group that async task is complete.  This last part is what I am struggling with here.  Unfortunately I cannot make changes to the underlying business logic, I can't necessarily just move all that logic to a service, I just need to get that last step working.

Comment: So, I've injected the Hub Context into the Api Controller, and it does work and is able to send messages to the sampleHub, however when I inject the Hub Context in the same way in the WebJob, it does not seem to send any messages, although it doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: Alright, I spoke to one of my coworkers and I came to the conclusion that this issue might just be because the api and the webjob are simply two different applications running with different contexts.  In that case this issue I am running into requires so architecture-related changes.  I have discovered one potential solution would be to run the webjob as if it were a client connected to the hub the other clients are connected to.  I will research that further and close down this question.  Thanks for the help!